# Error when build Android Cordova app with Crosswalk plugin : "NDK integration is deprecated in the current plugin"

Tags: android, cordova, android-ndk, crosswalk

If I add the crosswalk plugin and try to build the app in Android Studio, the build fails with and error:

```
Error:(187, 0) Error: NDK integration is deprecated in the current plugin.
Consider trying the new experimental plugin.
For details, see http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental.
Set "android.useDeprecatedNdk=true" in gradle.properties to continue using the current NDK integration.
```

I'm using cordova 6.1.1 and Crosswalk plugin version 1.6.1.
The Android Studio version is 1.5.2.

I tried to create the gradel.properties file and add the "android.useDeprecatedNdk=true" prop inside the file. But the build still fails.

I also saw the url: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental and searched for a way to install and config the "experimental plugin", but I don't know how to do it...

Can someone help?